# Getstream chat initializes after activity is put in background and then back in foreground

Tags: android, getstream-io

I implemented the Getstream chat into my Android app, but the chat only loads after I put the app in the background and come back to it. Before that, inside `onCreate` where I do all the logic like in the example [here](https://getstream.io/tutorials/android-chat/#java). 
The only relevant to Getstream in logs is:

`2019-10-03 09:40:54.718 11323-11485/com.test.test D/WebSocketService: WebSocket Response : {"connection_id":"a39a2311-cffb-4675-9977-049ae5a52c32","cid":"*","type":"health.check","created_at":"2019-10-03T07:40:53.129735005Z"}`

I tried putting all the code in `onStart`, `onResume` and so on, but nothing worked. What could the issue be?

I really don't think I should post the code since it's EXACTLY the same as in example. If you really need some, let me know.

EDIT: Best explained here: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-android/issues/95

Comment: Upon launching the ChatActivity the progress bar is spinning and after I put the app in background and come back, the chat shows as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed on the 2.2.0 release.

The same problem can also be caused by the lifecycle-extension library. `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0` works well but at the moment 2.2.0 has some weird bug.

Comment: True, forgot to update the issue. Sorry and thank you very much.